# Accessing functions in the window object

Tags: javascript

If I type: `window['alert']` in the console it will find the `alert()` function.

However if I type: `window['location.replace']`

It will be `undefined`. Why can't I access the `location.replace` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`replace()` is a function found in the object `window.location`, or `window['location']`, so you will have to write:

```
window.location.replace
```

or

```
window['location']['replace']
```

Comment: Let's say I pass the function I want as a string e.g. `location.replace` that is stored in `callback`. How would I call this? As `window[callback]();` wouldn't work.

Comment: In fact I've asked a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837462/custom-confirmation-dialog-callbacks-for-sub-objects

Answer (score 4):

What you want is `window['location']['replace']` (or `window['location'].replace`).

"location.replace" is not inside of "window". Rather, "replace" is inside of "location", which is inside of "window". Thus, it must be accessed in that order.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's an object structure, not just the name with a dot. You can access it many different ways:

```
window.location.replace
window["location"].replace
window["location"]["replace"]
```

and so on…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue the logic of `window['alert']` use `window['location']['replace']`.

When accessing `window['location.replace']` the name of the property you are accessing is `location.replace`, while what you want is the `.replace` property of the object referenced to as window.location.

If you want to access objects by the so-called "object path" you need to construct a function that will split the object path `"location.replace".split('.')` and then use recursion or a loop to reach to the property you're looking for.

Luckily there are packages for that, e.g. [object- path](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path) that can do this job for you, but of course you need to consider whether you need a whole external library (albeit tiny) for your task.

See more about Bracket notation [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

Answer (score -1):

location function is under the window, but you can use directly this: `location['replace']`