# Custom confirmation dialog callbacks for sub-objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a custom confirmation dialog that can take a callback and parameters to be executed if the user confirms the action.

```
function Confirm( text, callback, params )
{
    var html = '\
        <div class="modal-header clearfix">\
            <h1 class="title">Confirm</h1>\
        </div>\
        <div class="modal-content">\
            <p>' + ( text != null ? text : 'Are you sure you want to do this?' ) + '</p>\
        </div>\
        <div class="modal-footer clearfix">\
            <div class="float-right">\
                <div class="btn-group">\
                    <button class="btn ajax-modal-close">Cancel</button>\
                </div>\
                <div class="btn-group">\
                    <button class="btn important confirm">Ok</button>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    ';

    Modal.dataModal(html, 640, 320); // Custom Modal framework

    $('.confirm').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(callback)
        {
            if(params)
            {
                callback = callback.replace(/window./gi, ''); // remove window. prefix so we can call the callback on the window object below
                if(Array.isArray(params))
                {
                    window[callback].apply(window, params);
                }
                else
                {
                    window[callback].call(window, params);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                window[callback]();
            }
        }
        Modal.closeModal( $('.Modal').last() ); // Custom Modal framework
    });
}
```

And an example of calling this function would be:

`Confirm('Are you sure? All your data will be lost!', 'window.location.replace', '../');`

So if the user confirms this action, it will redirect them to the previous page.

However this doesn't work for sub-objects, such as `replace` which belongs to `location` and not `window`. To call this I would need to call it like: `window['location']['replace'].call(..`

**How can I handle sub-objects? When they are passed as strings.**

As if I call it directly in the console width: `window['location']['replace'].call(window, '../');` it gives the error: `Illegal invocation`.

Comment: I have replied to this concern in response to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836433/accessing-functions-in-the-window-object/31836640#31836640) and the reply got downvoted for no reason. See that answer.

Comment: @IgorR Not sure why you have been downvoted either. Do you know why `window['location']['replace'].call(window, '../');` throws an error though? Because even if I solve the sub-object issue, it still seems to error...

Comment: because location.replace nees location as its context (this) - not the window, so window["location"]["replace"].call(window.location, "../") will work.
In general you would need to pass the last object before the method in your object path as context (e.g. for window.x.y.z do window.x.y.z.call(window.x.y, params)

Comment: @IgorR Think you could put up an answer that handles this? Seems like you know how to fix my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Basically how would I pass the correct object path to `window[callback]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct function and context you can do something like this:

```
var func_parts = callback.split("."),
    context = callback = window;

$.each( func_parts, function(index){
    if( this != "window" ) callback = callback[this];
    if( index == func_parts.length - 2 ) context = callback;
});
```

then use it like this:

```
if (callback) {
    if (params) {
        if (Array.isArray(params)) {
            callback.apply(context, params);
        } else {
            callback.call(context, params);
        }
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the context while travelling down the object path.
Something like the code below would work, but as mentioned in the comment you may use something like [object-path](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path) for a general solution.

```
var context = window, 
    split = callback.split('.'),
    foo = split.shift();

if(foo == 'window')
    foo = split.shift();

while(split.length)
{
    context = context[foo];
    foo = split.shift();
}
```

at the end of this you will have the correct `context` and `foo` to do

```
context[foo].call(context, params);
```